# ToolStripMenuItem click event not working

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to open a file dialog window by pressing the "Open" button (`ToolStripMenuItem`) but it's not working for some reason (no errors, just not working).

It's working if i'll write exactly the same code in the method:

```
toolStripDropDownButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}
```

but it doesn't work for methods of menu items. Any idea?

```
    private void openFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Title = "Find the .assets file to backup",

                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,

                DefaultExt = ".assets",
                Filter = "assets files (*.assets)|*.assets",
                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true,

                ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                ShowReadOnly = true
            };

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Visible = true;
                textBox2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
    }
```

[example of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qDub.jpg)

Comment: Double check your Click event if it is properly associated with the MenuStrips and fires when its clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click on your `ToolStripMenuItem` (which in this case its name I suppose is: "openFileToolStripMenuItem");
- Goto Properties (Right-click on item > Properties or press F4 Key);
- [image: List item] Click "Events";
- [image: List item] Look for "Click" entry and on the right column type: `openFileToolStripMenuItem_Click` (which is your EventHandler name).

Your problem was that your component wasn't associated with the `EventHandler` you were coding.

To avoid this kind of issue with any type of event, add your `EventHandler` method name in the properties just like I explained to you above.

---

**WARNING:** after associating a `EventHandler` method, deleting it from the .cs file without removing from the Properties or the Designer.cs file, will cause [CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) compile error. In this case, just remove the line that VS will mark as error.

For instance:

[image]

Double click it and remove the highlighted row:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working. You're amazing! :)

Comment: @AxilleasDevAxe please be careful to the warning edit!

Comment: @AxilleasDevAxe glad it helped. :) please accept this answer as correct if you think it is and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok i've got you. Thank you again and i'll keep an eye on it. :)